# After 15 years in biomedical research and 11 years hiatus what career options do I have left?

Tags: career-path, job-search, social-media, science-communication

I had a very exciting research career (stem cells) PhD with the group that cloned Dolly, post docs at NYU and Cornell, even Assistant Professor in Memphis. Not a great publication record but my mentors always wrote amazing references saying I was top 5% scientist they met.

Then we moved a lot, I found it harder to apply for jobs and stopped
for 11 years.
Now I need a job and don’t know how to use my CV. Research seems a nonstarter. A couple of years ago I almost got a Research Scientist position but didn’t go through now I am getting no replies. Also tried teaching/college but also a nonstarter because I don’t have formal teaching experience.

What else can I try? Other career paths that might be open to me? Any certification, course that might revamp my CV and help reinvent myself?

I also have a Veterinary Medicine degree (Italy), a Masters from London Zoo, and what I enjoy the most is love reading and writing about science, science communication on social media or other platforms.

Comment: If you almost got a research scientist position two years ago, then perhaps something like that is still possible and you should carry on applying to positions like that. Have you kept up-to-date with veterinary medicine or your research field? Have you published science communications articles recently?

Comment: I haven’t any recent publications and my Vet Degree is from Italy and it is a complicated and long process to have it re-certified in the States. I’ll just keep trying. Thank you so much for the reply.

Comment: I didn't mean recent publications - I meant just reading other people's research, or maybe going to conferences. If you have a convincing reason for the hiatus and you are still in touch with things, that might help. Also could you talk to people that you previously worked with, to ask for advice?

Comment: There's a tremendous shortage of vets in the States.